# webservice deployment issue

Tags: web-services, asmx

I  deployed webservice written in .net language through IIS from my local machine,Is there any possible way to access remote HTTP server which contain different OS and different technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being confused, but can you define:

> different OS and different
>   technologies

1. Do you mean deploy your webservice **to** another host **or**
2. Do you mean **consume** a webservice from another host?

**Option 1**

If the host is not running IIS/ASP.NET I think you are going to have some issues as Mono may not run what your code base requires.

But you could try the following:

1. publish your site to a folder
2. zip up that folder
3. scp/ftp/upload this zip to the remote server
4. unzip the files (or upload individual files/folder) to directory configured by IIS Management
5. try to run

**Option 2**

You need to use either the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool to create the proxy clients to consume that webservice or you use the [Add Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28VS.80%29.aspx) in Visual Studio to automate this for you.

Hope this answers your requirements. Update your question with more information for the community to offer more support.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is one of the main things that web services are for.

Comment: yes it is ,,But my question is if deployed through My local machine IIS it will give the URL as http://localhost/Alias/service.asmx,,so if i replaced the localhost with my IP address it can be there in systems in same LAN,but what about other systems locted in remote HTTP server which is on different network

Comment: Yes,i agreed..if deployed through My local machine IIS it will give the URL as localhost/Alias/service.asmx,,so if i replaced the localhost with my IP address it can be there in systems in same LAN,but what about other systems locted in remote HTTP server which is on different network

Comment: I think your question is about how to setup a webserver for incoming connections from the internet rather than ".net webservice deploy".